# Installing Tweepy on OS x

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have been trying to install tweepy on OSx via

```
pip install tweepy
```

I have already installed pip, but I am getting this strange error message I haven't come accross before and, obviously Tweepy doesn't import at all (because it hasn't installed).

I get the following error message:

error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tests': Permission denied

Is there any way that I can grant permission? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Extra information: running Python 2.7 if you couldn't tell from the path

Comment: google `virtualenv` (you can solve it with `sudo pip ...`, but I do not recommend that)

Comment: @alko How come? What is different?

Comment: different with what? You don't have access priveleges for `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` where pip installs modules by default, and need root access, here sudo. Virtualenv let you easily manage packages in user based folder along with many other features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Alko, you need root access to write to the directory where pip stores the packages.

You can type:

```
sudo su
```

in the terminal and then type:

```
pip install tweepy
```

Alternatively, you can use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv):

> "What if you can't install packages into the global site-packages directory? For instance, on a shared host.
>
> In all these cases, virtualenv can help you. It creates an environment that has its own installation directories, that doesn't share libraries with other virtualenv environments (and optionally doesn't access the globally installed libraries either)."

Basically, it will allow you to create isolated environments for each of your python projects and will allow you to sidestep the permissions issue you are having.

For a good explanation see: [Installing Python on Mac OS X: virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/#virtualenv)

Comment: Brilliant answer! Thank you so much for you detailed explanation. It worked great and I have done some additional reading to help back this up.